# Store char data from serial read before print or send to database

Tags: serialization, arduino, hex, buffer, store

I'm using arduino to send hex data to external hardware and recive data reply from hardware when it read card.
Hex I've sent : BB 01 FF 00 01 15 16 7E
And the reply I've recieve and I printed to serial : BB 02 22 00 11 D0 34 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 12 14 11 62 77 69 EA 7E
How I can store the whole data that I recieve first, so I can send whole data/char to database.
Now I can only send the first data I recieve (BB or 0xbb)

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial serial(D5,D6);

//#define DEBUG
unsigned char incomingByte;

void sendIdentifyCmd ()
{
  serial.write (0xbb);    
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);
  serial.write (0x22);  
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);                  
  serial.write ((byte)0x00);                  
  serial.write (0x22);
  serial.write (0x7e);              
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print (0xbb);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x22);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x00);
  Serial.print (0x22);
  Serial.print (0x7e);
  Serial.println ();
#endif
}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("begin initial Serial!\n");
}

void loop ()
{
  sendIdentifyCmd ();
  delay (2);
  while(serial.available () > 0)
  {
      incomingByte=serial.read ();
      if (incomingByte <= 0x0F) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print (incomingByte,HEX);
      Serial.print (' ');
      
  }
  Serial.println ();
  delay (1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple Array to store the received hex data. When you have received the sufficient amount of data you can store or print it.
For example array can be initiated with capacity of 100 hex numbers and increment the variable to track the current index of the array. As and when the index is about to reach 100 the contents of array can be printed or stored in database. After that repeat the process.

Comment: I've tried this code, but it just print ""abc: 2abc: 5"
Do you have any clue?

void loop ()
{
  sendIdentifyCmd ();
  delay (2);
  while(serial.available () > 0)
  {
      incomingByte=serial.read ();
     
      if (incomingByte <= 0x0F) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print (incomingByte,HEX);
      Serial.print (' ');
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
  while(serial.available()>0)
  {
    abc=serial.readBytesUntil(0xFF, buffer, 24);
    Serial.print("abc: ");
    Serial.print(abc, HEX);
  }
  Serial.println ();
  delay (1000);
}

Comment: Are you expecting SendIdentofyCmd() to execute after each serial read or only once.